# SVN type layout for GIT

Tags: git

Please have a look at the following figure

[image]

I am coming from SVN background and there I saw changes in files right away. Can some please let me know how can we do the same with GIT on windows? by installing some software or something.
I am running a GIT whose details are as follows.
[image]

Please note that I already know how to do that using commands on git command line.

I tried to find out the way to enable the windows layout for git so that I may see changed files right away. May be the things that I searching are not the right terminology.

Comment: I think that git for windows has a shell extension that allows that kind of behavior in windows explorer. i am not a Windows user myself so I can't really tell how it's doing these day but I would assume it's still there,

Comment: This looks relevant. https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.4/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would rely on:

- command line (`git status`)
- [IDE integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) (like GitLens with Visual Studio Code)

Adding Windows file explorer integration means Administrator privilege during installation (which most of us do not have in a corporate environment).

However, [Tortoise for Git](https://tortoisegit.org/) includes such an integration.

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/Overlays.png]